# Creating SQL Parametric View based Layer in QGIS?

Tags: wms, qgis-server

How to create SQL Parametric View based Layer in QGIS (like in [GeoServer](https://geoserver.geo-solutions.it/edu/en/adding_data/add_sqllayers.html) [documentation](https://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/data/database/sqlview.html))?

I have PostGIS spatial data. There I have my own function, that does something. I execute it from GeoServer:

```
select * from my_scheme.get_geom_all('%T_KEY%','%KPI_NAME%','%FLTR%')
```

This function gets params via a web app (`&viewparams=T_KEY:2018-12-01;KPI_NAME:any_KPI;FLTR:any_value_1>=FLTR:any_value_2<FLTR:any_value_3` )

On GeoServer it work fine but I have not been able to duplicate it on QGIS.

Comment: are you trying to show a WMS layer in QGIS? or replicate the view in QGIS?

Comment: I want moving my functionality by Geoserver to QGIS.

Comment: Now I try create layer from function. Like in GeoServer. But I don't now, how.

Comment: "are you trying to show a WMS layer in QGIS? or replicate the view in QGIS?" I prepare layer in QGIS and publish it by QGIS Server. Work with WMS layer doing by web application. And user must be change WMS request after 'viewparams'. E.g. change date.